# Android Studio: app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

When trying to run our Android Studio project we recently get a

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'

Error on one PC, on all other devices it is working fine however.

After some research we followed the guide for enabling multidex support (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) and since we are using SDK version 19 we added:

```
multiDexEnabled true

...

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

...

android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
```

However, even after running the `gradlew clean` command we now get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/appyvet/rangebar/RangeBar$1.class

Comment: Try to clean the project and check the dependencies if there are some trying to compile the same project.

Comment: Use only this, multiDexEnabled true, rest multidex part remove it.

Comment: @MuratK. As I have said, we run gradlew clean before running

Comment: @Shekhar Already tried this, same result

Comment: And the second part of my comment? Check the dependency tree for duplicates  with `./gradlew app:dependencies`